# Anyone knows a good implementation of file size as a value object in PHP?

Tags: php, oop

In project i came across a lot of references to disk or file sizes(in bytes, kilo, mega etc) so i though this is a very good candidate for a value object like Money or Quantity. I wonder if anyone has ever done this before in php. Thanks.

Comment: You could look at SPL's [FileInfo](http://php.net/manual/en/class.splfileinfo.php). I know it's not exactly what you asked for but it does provide a standardised class for a similar purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Zend_Measure_Binary](http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/1.11/Zend_Measure/Zend_Measure_Binary/Zend_Measure_Binary.html)...

```
$measure = new Zend_Measure_Binary($size, Zend_Measure_Binary::BYTE);
$size = $measure->convertTo(Zend_Measure_Binary::MEGABYTE);
```